# Every 3 disjoint closed subsets of normal space can be separated with 3 disjoint open subsets

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a normal space ($T_4$),and let $F_1,F_2,F_3$ be closed disjoint subsets of X.

Prove that there are $U_1,U_2,U_3$ open disjoint subsets,such that $F_i$ is subset of $U_i$ for each $1\le i \le 3$.

I'm not even sure how to begin this..any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: First use normality to get disjoint open nbhds $U_1$ and $V$ of $F_1$ and $F_2\cup F_3$, respectively. Then use it to get $U_2$ and $U_3$ inside $V$.

Comment: How about this- I use the normality of X and find disjoint subsets for $F_2,F_3$ and take the intersection of those open subsets with the $V$ you mentioned?

Comment: @ChakaChaka: Yes, that works fine.